# Get attribute of html tag - Enlive

Tags: clojure, enlive

I was trying to get `src` attribute of `img` tag that has attribute `itemprop` set to some value.

Ok, I got the `img` tag and I'm able to extract inner text according to quesetion I asked here earlier today (in this case there is no text obviously), but I can't find anything that would help me return value of `src` attribute

```
(:require [net.cgrand.enlive-html :as e])

(defn getbyitemprop 
  "Extract node content from HTML"
  [html value]
  (e/select-nodes* (e/html-snippet html)
             [(e/attr= :itemprop value) e/text-node]))
```

This gets me inner text of element by itemprop I pass as an argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you want the tag, which contains the attributes and contents, so you would drop the `net.cgrand.enlive-html/text-node` part of the selector.

```
(defn getbyitemprop
  "Extract node content from HTML"
  [html value]
  (e/select-nodes* (e/html-snippet html)
                   [(e/attr= :itemprop value)]))

(getbyitemprop
  "<p itemprop=\"description\" src=\"testvalue\"> Some content I want to extract </p>"
  "description")
;=> ({:tag :p, 
;     :attrs {:src "testvalue", :itemprop "description"}, 
;     :content (" Some content I want to extract ")})
```

This works for dynamic strings of html, if you want more general transformations for files, or resources in general, take a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/cgrand/enlive/) for `deftemplate` and `defsnippet`.

Comment: this works but when I try to get value of `:src` with `(get-in (getbyitemprop html "description") [:attrs :src])` I keep getting `nil`. Same thing with `get`

Comment: `net.cgrand.enlive-html/select-nodes*` returns a list of matches, because you can potentially have more than one match. So, you can either `(get-in (first (getbyitemprop html "description")) [:attrs :src])` or use `map` on the collection.

Comment: thanks. Didn't notice parentheses around curly braces. You have been great help to me